# Get csv and compare lines. ArrayList? Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

i dont't use java very often and now i got some Problem.
I want to read a CSV file like this one:

> A,B,C,D
>   A,B,F,K
>   E,F,S,A
>   A,B,C,S
>   A,C,C,S

Java don't know dynamic arrays, so i choose an ArrayList. This works so far. The Problem is:
How can I store the ArrayList? I think an other ArrayList would help.
This is what I got:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "../data/" + filename + ".csv")));

    List rows = new ArrayList(); 

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        rows.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));

    }
```

Now I get an ArrayList with a size of 5 for `rows.size()`.
How do I get row[0][0] for example?

What do I want to do? The Problem is i want to find the same row except the last column. 
For example i want to find row 0 and row 3. 
thank you very much

Thank you all! You helped me a lot. =) Maybe Java and I will become friends =) **THANKS!**

Comment: You could read the csv line by line, and store every entry (without the last column) in a HashSet. Then, if you read a new line, you could check if the HashSet already contains the same entry (using the contains() method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the row size in advance, String.split() returns a String array:

```
List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    rows.add(line.split(",", -1));
```

To access a specific row:

```
int len = rows.get(0).length;
String val = rows.get(0)[0];
```

Also, are you always comparing by the entire row except the last column?  You could just take off the last value (`line.replaceFirst(",.*?$", "")`) and compare the rows as strings (have to be careful of whitespace and other formatting, of course).

A slightly different way:

```
Set<String> rows = new HashSet<String>(); 

String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    if(!rows.add(line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(','))))
        System.out.println("duplicate found: " + line);
}
```

Of course, modify as necessary if you actually need to capture the matching lines.

Comment: Wait. "rows" is a list of "String[]", but you're adding line, which is a "String". Unless I'm missing something, you're code won't compile!

Comment: line.split() returns an Array of strings, or not?

Comment: I'm adding the result of line.split(), which is String[] (an array of Strings)

Comment: The reason `rows.get(0).get(0)` doesn't work in your code is that you didn't specify a type for `List rows`, so the contents of `rows` is treated as `Object`.  Should be: `List<List<String>> rows` (if you really want to use lists, I like my way better).

Comment: With your way i got this now running. I can access every element by row and column. Now the compare part...

Comment: For most csv files, this isn't a big problem, but `String.split(",")` could split in the middle of a field, if the field contains commas, which are legal in csv. Just a warning. See the rfc spec at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare an ArrayList of arrays. Asuming that csv file has a known number of columns, the only dynamic list needed here are the "rows" of your "table", formed by an ArrayList(rows) of arrays char[] (columns). (If not, then an ArrayList of ArrayList is fine).

It's just like a 2D table in any other language: an array of arrays. Just that in this case one of the arrays needs to be dynamic.

To read the file you'll need two loops. One that reads each line, just as you're doing, and another one that reads char per char.

Just a quick note: if you are going to declare an array like this:

```
char[] row = new char[5];
```

and then going to add each row to the ArrayList like this:

```
yourList.add(row);
```

You will have a list full of pointers to the same array. You'll need to use the .clone() method like this:

yourList.add(row.clone());

To access it like table[1][2], you'll need to use arraylist.get(1).get(2);

Comment: Each row of the csv has the same number of columns in the same csv. But different csv files have different numbers of columns.

Comment: Then use another ArrayList, but keep in mind the .clone() method. It will still be needed. Btw, to access it like table[1][2], you'll need to use arraylist.get(1).get(2);

Comment: I tried to find out the number of columns with: rows.get(0).size()  but this doesn't work. What do you mean with the .clone() method? Why do I need this?

Comment: Also, don't forget to declare the thing you're going to put in the List: List<ArrayList> or List<Integer>, when declaring them

Comment: @user515466: Use an arraylist of arraylist if you want. You need to clone() method because in my example, row is just a pointer to an array. If you add "row" to a List, then you have a list of pointers, and all the pointers point to the same memory block you declared with "new char[5]". To avoid this, you must clone the pointer, so that what you add is the content of the memory pointed by the pointer and no the pointer itself.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried 2 arraylists but while accessing these wit row.get(0).get(0)  I get the error: The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object